# Error: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

En mi `app.config` tengo las siguientes `keys`:

```
<add key="File_1" value="00.00.00.000\C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXXX\ABC"/>

<add key="File_2" value="00.00.00.000\C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXXX\EFG"/>

<add key="File_3" value="00.00.00.000\C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXX\XXXX\HIJ"/>
```

Con `00.00.00.00` me refiero a la `ip` de la maquina, ya que estare extrayendo los archivos desde ahi.

En mi `Form1.cs`, guardo las direcciones en variables `string`

```
 string folder_1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["File_1"];
 string folder_2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["File_2"];
 string folder_3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["File_3"];
```

Después hago una `array` de las variables:

```
string[] folders = { folder_1, Folder_2, Folder_3 };
```

Este es el eresultado de cada uno en el array:

```
00.00.00.000\\C:\\XXX\\XXXXX\\XXXXXX\\XXXXX\\ABC
00.00.00.000\\C:\\XXX\\XXXXX\\XXXXXX\\XXXXX\\EFG
00.00.00.000\\C:\\XXX\\XXXXX\\XXXXXX\\XXXXX\\HIJ
```

En esta parte deberia de crear una `array` de todos los archivos que estan en esa direccion:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder_1);
```

Sin embargo se detiene y manda este error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The given path's format is not
>   supported.

Como puedo solucionar este problema y que lo ocasiona?

Answer (score 0):

El formato no es reconocido como un directorio del sistema ya que debería tener este formato: `C:\\XXX\\XXXXX\\XXXXXX\\XXXXX\\ABC`, te sugiero que antes de introducir los valores al array deberías eliminar esta parte `00.00.00.000\`, ejemplo:

```
  folder_1 = folder_1.Replace("00.00.00.000\\", "");
  folder_2 = folder_2.Replace("00.00.00.000\\", "");
  folder_3 = folder_3.Replace("00.00.00.000\\", "");

  string[] folders = { folder_1, folder_2, folder_3 };
```

Comment: Esto si elimino las ip al inicio de cada uno, pero ahora me salta este error al llegar a la misma linea

`Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\XXX\XXX\XXXX\XXX\File_1`

Ya revise la ruta del archivo y es correcta.

Comment: @Madre ok, el directorio que marco error , existe? Eso es causa de ese problema

Answer (score 0):

Tiene dos problemas.  Primero, el formato es

```
\\IP\<sharename>\carpeta\archivo
```

por ejemplo:

```
\\192.168.25.22\UsarioA\Hola.pdf
```

El segundo problema es que no se puede usar C: con un nombre UNC.  Tiene que ser el nombre de un "share."  (Dependiendo en el contexto, el nombre puede ser c$).  Puede share una carpeta con right-click->Sharing.